# Google Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango, tango

So I've seen how the Project tango tablet can create a 3D mesh of the room you're standing in. My question is, will you be able to move objects that have been mapped in the room? If it's moving day and you want to know if there is any way to fit that damn couch through that door, would you be able to simulate this?

Comment: This is definitely not the site to ask for that.

Comment: You might want to ask that question here -- https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114537896428695886568

Comment: StackOverflow is a site about specific programming problems, not about feature requests or discussions about a library or tool. Please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) pages before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to take virtual measurements using Tango. However, it is likely no more productive at doing so than would be an ordinary measuring tape.

Comment: Tango's MeasureIt app is more productive than a physical measuring tape when measuring between points that are hard to reach. Like inside a long, narrow space (back of a closet or inside a machine). Or just on/near a ceiling (which would require scrambling up and down a physical ladder. Also it's hard to reach with tape between points that are farther apart than a couple meters, holding both ends, when it's just one person measuring. With MeasureIt you just point and tap around the object or room (within about 4 meters from you).

Comment: You could MeasureIt the couch from one corner to the diagonally opposite corner, then MeasureIt the doorway for clearance within 15-30 seconds, all by yourself. A physical tape measure would probably take at least 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

'Tangosaurus' demos an Augmented reality app that places virtual elements in a real world, using Project Tango.  Another demo shows how a room could be scanned in and interacted with using basic physics objects(spheres in this case).

As long as you can use the Tango in an environment that isn't saturated with IR light (exterior during direct sunlight), you could simulate virtual furniture rearrangement.  No such app exists yet that I know of, however there is a virtual tape measure that's maybe accurate enough for basic planning.  I used it to test if some shelving would fit in the desired location.  It worked fine for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an App for measuring distance using Project Tango: [MeasureIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projecttango.tangomeasureit&hl=en)